# SQL data modeling, a column with multiple values

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I am working on a list of courses at my uni, and for each course I store the ID, name, credits and prerequisite courses. The problem is some courses have multiple prerequisite courses, how should I go about this ? I did some research and apparently, multiple values in one column is not the proper way of modeling data. Help is appreciated.

Comment: A separate table with composite primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php

First normal form prohibits multiple values. Typically, you're looking for at least 3NF in standard data modelling.